# Self-returning class?

Tags: c++, class, reference, instantiation

I was wondering if (in C++) you can  instantiate a class (class foo) then have said class return the already instantiated object. (foo::instance())

In other words, can I have a class return it's-self via it's own methods? I want to be able to create a class (i.e. class foo) early in my program so it is already setup and ready to go. Then, farther down the line, I want to be able to call functions from that class without having to pass that object as an argument to my calling function. Can I do something like so:
`MyClass::ReturnSelf()->foo();`
or
`MyClass::ReturnSelf().foo();`

EDIT: I just realized this might be a little unclear. I want to be able to have another class call this "self-returning" method so it can use the already instantiated object's methods and members without creating a new object.

Comment: Sure.  One idiom is ["factory methods"](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/factory_method/cpp/1).  One application is ["Singleton"](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/singleton/cpp/1)

Comment: Class? Object? What are we talking about?

Comment: This resembles the `clone` method.

Comment: If you want it "like so: `MyClass::ReturnSelf()->foo();`" and also want to be able to derive from your class one day, see my answer :D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Congrats, you've discovered the [singleton pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern). Quite a caveat, if you didn't already know it.

```
struct X
{
   static X& instance()
   {
       static X x;
       return x;
   }

   void foo();
};
```

and call the method as:

```
X::instance().foo();
```

Of course, you could also make the method `static`, if that's an option, and call it directly:

```
X::foo(); //this requires foo to be declared static
```

The effect of returning the instance from methods can also be used for method chaining:

```
struct Element
{
    Element& setColor() { return *this; }
    Element& setWidth() { return *this; }
};

Element e;
e.setColor().setWidth();
```

Comment: `e.setColor().setWidth();` this get compiled to exactly the same binary than the version with two independent calls but is much more unreadable and unpredictable code!

Comment: @rhavin How is it more unreadable or unpredictable? You're setting the color, and then you're setting the width.

Comment: you have to actually know that setColor() returns the object and not – for example – the old Color, what one would expect. You already have `e`. But in your case, you also have to know, what SetColor retuns. So you need more knowledge about the code with no further benefit gaining from it.

Comment: depending on the compiler, it may also get compiled much more inefficiently, and you loose the ability to act apropiate if one of those methods fail.

Comment: @rhavin to some it is surpising, to others it's [an idiom](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/named-parameter-idiom.html).

Answer (score 0):

A `static` member function usually does the trick:

```
struct Foo
{
    static Foo & special_instance()
    {
        static Foo impl;  // Alarm bells: This is a global state!
        return impl;
    }

    // ...
};
```

Usage (from anywhere in the code):

```
Foo & f = Foo::special_instance();
// ...
```

You have the additional option of making all the constructors of the class `private` so that this sort of object creation is the *only* option. This is generally awkward design, but there may be situations where it is useful. Just be mindful whether you're modeling your problem correctly or whether you might get away with something simpler.

Comment: the problem with that approach is: you cant derive from foo

Comment: @rhavin: Well, that's true, though whether it's a "problem" depends on the desired design!

Answer (score 0):

> I just realized this might be a little unclear. I want to be able to have another class call this "self-returning" method so it can use the already instantiated object's methods and members without creating a new object.

define a class-variable in class foo of type foo that you can return in static class method instance(). You may also try to give it type *foo and set it up with a pointer on first ctor, wich makes it possible to derive from your class.

```
class Foo
{
   # class variable pointing to first instance
   static foo* pFoo = null;

   # constructor, sets pointer to first instance 
   Foo()
   {
      if (!pFoo) pFoo = this;
      /* ... */
   }

   # static class method returning instance
   static foo* instance() {return pFoo;}
}
```